# Azure Logic Apps EDIFACT DECODE Allow underscore(_) character in

Tags: azure-logic-apps, edifact

I am using Azure Logic Apps and Integration Accounts for receiving the EDIFACT messages.

The EDIFACT incoming message has an underscore character in it, and EDIFACT DECODE validation fails with the message:

> Error encountered during parsing. The Edifact transaction set with id
>   '1' contained in interchange (without group) with id '1', with sender
>   id 'XXX', receiver id 'XXXXX' is being suspended with following
>   errors:
>
> Error: 1 (Field level error)
>
> SegmentID: BGM
>
> Position in TS: 2
>
> Data Element ID: XXXX
>
> Position in Segment: 3
>
> Position in Field: 1
>
> Data Value: 1_2017-09-2206:24:42
>
> 21: Invalid character found

I want to allow the underscore character to be considered as valid character, appreciate any pointers in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's all driven by the standard character set, [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/edi-character-sets), I don't recall any that supports underscore, so ultimately the transaction is incorrect according to the EDIFACT standard as the error message states.

Comment: Thanks Don, I know underscore is not valid in any of the EDIFACT character sets. Was looking to see if there is an easy way to allow it.

Answer (score 0):

There are 1.5 problems. :)

But, the first thing you need to do is inform your management that your **Trading Partner is sending invalid EDIFACT**.  If the Trading Partner is not able to solve their problem, you will have to spend extra time accommodating their issue.

**This is not a problem with you, your app or BizTalk Server.**

EDIFACT supports a very limited number of character sets and "_" is not in any of them.

Either they fix their problem or you will have to create a custom Function that removes/changes the invalid characters.

Finally, the .5 problem is that they're not even sending a usable value.  That format is not any standard date format so manipulation would be required anyway to use it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, I agree, if there is no in-built way to allow "_" character, will need to create the function to handle that.

Comment: I think the field throwing this error was BGM_02 which is the "Document Identifier" - a string of up to 70 characters assigned by the sender. There's no expectation that it should be able to be parsed as a date.

Answer (score 0):

UNOC (ISO-8859-1 / Latin1) character set includes the underscore.

I wouldn't expect great support for characters where the encoding is different between ISO-8859-1, Windows-1252 or the first 255 code-points of UTF-8 (meaning characters `0x80` to `0x9F`), due to the potential for implementations to use either Windows-1252.

I also wouldn't rely on any non-printable or white-space characters (other than space) being handled consistently well.